# 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' en rojo

Tags: android

¿Por qué me aparece esto en rojo?

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

Dice esto en el warning:

> ll com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

Aquí mi gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "doctorbateria.masterclean.speed.booster"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "2.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}



}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

// Dagger 2
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"



implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'

implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.4'

implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'

implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-js-rhino:1.3.1'

implementation 'com.github.pluscubed:recycler-fast-scroll:0.3.1@aar'
implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.john990:WaveView:16a10c1f9b'
implementation 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularfillableloaders:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'


implementation 'com.mikepenz:actionitembadge:3.2.5@aar'

implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.11@aar'
implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'
implementation 'com.jenzz:materialpreference:1.3'
implementation 'com.jaredrummler:android-processes:1.0.9'
implementation project(':orm-library')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'



}
```

Comment: Revisaste la información que te proporcione?

Answer (score 1):

El error indica:

> Las libraries com.android.support deben usar exactamente la misma
> especificación de versión (mezclar versiones puede provocar bloqueos
> en tiempo de ejecución).

De hecho lo  puedes ver directamente en las dependencias, ya que algunas se mostrarán sobre un color rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Cambiar la misma la misma especificación de acuerdo a tu versión

para realizar esto coloca el puntero del mouse sobre cada dependencia y teclea

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

se abrirá un menu contextual el cual te sugerira la versión a reemplazar de acuerdo a tu configuración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es importante que sepas que aunque reemplaces por la última versión adecuada a tu configuración puede ser que se continué mostrando el indicador rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para evitar esto agrega arriba de la declaración de la dependencia:

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
```

de esta forma definitivamente no se mostrará el indicador rojo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]